# Resizing Div and its content dynamically to fit the browser height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to optimize my website to different screen and window sizes. I want the content of a div to take up 100% of the browser height, not more than that, so that the user doesn't have to scroll down. I am not sure how to implement this, I tried this

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    $('.container-narrow').width($(this).width());
    $('.container-narrow').height($(this).height());
)};
```

But this doesnt seem to work, the content still goes over the browser height. and I have to endup scrolling

Comment: It's possible that `.container-narrow` has padding or margins that affect this.  Try using `.outerHeight`

Comment: If there is more content than fits on the screen what do you want to do about it?

Comment: Since you're using jQuery try this plugin [jquery.columns](https://github.com/elclanrs/jquery.columns) I made if you want to set up a responsive design in a jiffy. It might help you out. It let's you set up your layout very quickly using [viewport relative units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths), so it always adapts to the screen size.

Comment: Have you looked at a CSS solution instead? E.g. set `position: fixed; height: 100%, etc`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I tried .outerHeight as well, doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @KevinBoucher I dont have any other content on the screen, I just have one image and some text. I want text and image to shrink accordingly (and yes I am using Bootstrap as well)

Comment: @VladMagdalin I need the content to scale dynamically, so I dont think a css solution would work

Comment: @Jonathan You mean you need a responsive image? And what about the text? What does it mean for that to scale dynamically? Font-size? The amount of text?

Comment: @Jonathan - Unless your using IE6 (which I think even IE6 does it), any changes to content or browser window size will scale automatically as long as your css is right.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Yes The Font Size, or even the position like [here](http://www.briefeditions.com/)

Comment: @Tom I tried your suggested solution, it doesnt seem to work though

Comment: @Jonathan Care to elaborate?

Comment: Are you trying to scale text to fit into the page?

Comment: @Tom please have a look at [this](http://www.briefeditions.com/). This might explain. I dont want my content to go out of the window size. If the window size is smaller I want the image and the text to shrink to fit that screen and expand to fit the bigger and just stay at center ( I do know how to keep it at the center though)

Comment: @Jonathan That page will only shrink to a certain extent. I edited my answer to give you a similar setup though.

Comment: Why not allow the user to scroll? This question really doesn't make any sense to me. I might misunderstand, but it seems like you are creating a lot of problems to solve something that is not a problem.

Comment: @Kevin, I think the question is misleading. I think Jonathan is trying for a floating footer that essentially stays at the bottom of the page. I could be wrong, however.

Answer (score 0):

CSS will recalculate on resize.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body, html {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.body {
 height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: -100px;
}
.header {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
 text-align: center;
}
.content {
 text-align: center;
}
.footer {
 height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
    <div class="header">
    This is the header.
    </div>
    <div class="content">This is the content.</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
This is the footer.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```